# How To Fix The Error For the Network Error at node_modules\axios\lib\core\AxiosError.js:null in AxiosError

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i Call The API For User Creating using React Native , Get an Error and no any Response on click
and no any data print on console ...

we get the error like

Network Error
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\AxiosError.js:null in AxiosError
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:null in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:null in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:null in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:null in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";


const initialValue = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .required("Name is Missing"),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email("Invalide Email ")
    .required("Email is Missing "),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .required("Password is Missing")
    .min(8, "Password is too Short!"),

  repassword: yup.string().required("Re-Password is Missing !"),
});

const handleSignup = async (values, formikActions) => {
  try {
    const {data} = await axios.post("http//:192.168.0.103:4000/register", {
      ...values,
    }); 
    console.log(data);
    formikActions.resetForm();
    formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
const SignupScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValue}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={handleSignup}
    >
      {({
        errors,
        values,
        touched,
        handleBlur,
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
      }) => {
        // console.log(errors, values);
        return (
          <>
            <View style={aicaas.container}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, color: "grey" }}>
                User Registration
              </Text>
              <View style={aicaas.inputcontainer}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  {touched.name && errors.name ? errors.name : ""}
                </Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={aicaas.input}
                  onChangeText={handleChange("name")}
                  value={values.name}
                  onBlur={handleBlur("name")}
                  placeholder="Name"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={aicaas.inputcontainer}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  {touched.email && errors.email ? errors.email : ""}
                </Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={aicaas.input}
                  onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                  value={values.email}
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={aicaas.inputcontainer}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  {touched.password && errors.password ? errors.password : ""}
                </Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={aicaas.input}
                  onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
                  value={values.password}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={aicaas.inputcontainer}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  {touched.repassword && errors.repassword
                    ? errors.repassword
                    : ""}
                </Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={aicaas.input}
                  onChangeText={handleChange("repassword")}
                  value={values.repassword}
                  placeholder="Re-Password"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={aicaas.inputcontainer}>
                <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Register" />
              </View>
            </View>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

const aicaas = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "grey",
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  inputcontainer: {
    width: "80%",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});

export default SignupScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is from the endpoint `http//:192.168.0.103:4000/register`.

It should be `http://192.168.0.103:4000/register`

i.e `http://` not `http//:`

Comment: Same Error After Change It ....